# Check no dups in list and within number range

Tags: python, if-statement

I am attempting to check a list (of six numbers) for duplicates and that it falls within this number range (inclusive) 20 - 100.

I can get it to work for any number that is less than 20:

```
 for value in list_input:
        if len(list_input) != len(set(list_input)) or any(i <= 19 for i in list_input): 
            return "Entered incorrect number combination, please try again"
        else: 
            y = combination(81,6)
            return "Your chances of winning are 1:{:,}".format(int(y))
```

I tried this for line 2, but it doesn't work

```
if len(list_input) != len(set(list_input)) or any(100 < i <= 19 for i in list_input):
```

Am I just misunderstanding how List Comprehensions work?

Comment: Why did you tag `pandas` to this question?

Comment: Still new to Python and mainly use it for data analysis. I usually always include pandas. Just don't know enough, yet.

Comment: How do you expect to ever have `100 < 19`?

Comment: My logic must wrong. In my mind 100 < i <=19 is when i  is greater than 100 and less than or equal to 19

Comment: In which universe can i be greater 100 AND less/equal than 19?

Comment: Look, I said my logic was wrong. No need to pile on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `any`, why not to use `all`:

```
for value in list_input:
        if len(list_input) != len(set(list_input)) or not all(20 <= i <= 100 for i in list_input): 
            return "Entered incorrect number combination, please try again"
        else: 
            y = combination(81,6)
            return "Your chances of winning are 1:{:,}".format(int(y))
```